# compare two files in python

Tags: python, string

in a.txt i have the text(line one after the other)

```
login;user;name
login;user;name1
login;user
```

in b.txt i have the text

```
login;user
login;user
login;user;name2
```

after comparing it should display in a text file as

```
login;user;name
login;user;name1
login;user;name2....
```

How can it be done using python?

Comment: It is almost impossible to figure out the content of the text files from the above description. Try formatting it as code (four spaces in front of each line).

Comment: Please define the way the files are "compared". It looks more like a merging process, with some odd rules about what lines are kept are what lines are excluded.   For example, what happened to the "login;user" lines ?   If a merge (or a merge with some exclusion rules) is effectively required, can we assume the lines in each file are sorted ?

Comment: Looks like a line by line "word-wise" OR.

Comment: @waffleman: quite possibly! Let's see if noname cares to specify. No point in guessing with such a small sample; could be just about any rule (for ex. SilentGhost's awswer would also fit the sample, if only making several assumption such as "priority" for a, 3 fields expected etc.)

Answer (score 4):

```
for a, b in zip(open('a'), open('b')):
    print(a if len(a.split(';')) == 3 else b)
```

Comment: +1.  Note that this solution assumes the login;user portion of the lines are in the same order.  If they are not, you will need to reorder them (e.g. by sorting by line) or create a dictionary.  The latter technique is more complex and only needed if there are additional constraints not mentioned by the OP.

Comment: With what appears to be log files (hence "big" files), it might be advisable to drive the loop with iterator, using itertools.izip(), rather than building a possibly huge sequence first.

Comment: @mjv: it is iterator, in py3k

Comment: quite right, _in py3k_; I should have qualified "If you're in Py 2.x..."  Indeed this and other py3k improvements, along with the porting of critical libraries, will eventually (I think soon) "tip the balance", but until then, the bulk of Python coding seems to take place in 2.x

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the standard-lib `difflib` module can be of help - check out its documentation. Your question is not clear enough for a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the vague information given, I would try something like the following:

```
import itertools

def merger(fni1, fni2):
    "merge two files ignoring 'login;user\n' lines"
    fp1= open(fni1, "r")
    fp2= open(fni2, "r")
    try:
        for line in itertools.chain(fp1, fp2):
            if line != "login;user\n":
                yield line
    finally:
        fp1.close()
        fp2.close()

def merge_to_file(fni1, fni2, fno):
    with open(fno, "w") as fp:
        fp.writelines(merger(fni1, fni2))
```

The `merge_to_file` is the function you should use.